# How to make an inner class implementation of Runnable work with an Executor in java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a task that is being called from within a loop. The task goes for a one time Database hit. I wished to speed up the execution, so I created a runnable and passed it to an Executor.

```
public void run () {
  for (int i=0,size=5; i<5 ; i++) {
    doWork();
  }
}
// above is a part of Runnable implementation
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadExecutor(5);
service.execute(runnable);
service.shutdown();
// new code follows
for(Map.Entry entry : map.entrySet) {
  service.execute( new Runnable() { 
    public void run() {
      doWork(entry); // error : can't have a non-final variable in an inner class
    }
 });
}
service.shutdown();
```

I achieved my goal of disintegrating the job but the inner class does not take in a non-final variable. How do I divide the job and pass in to an executor? 
Thanks

Comment: Is it correct that you want all 5 threads to work on the same task, thus doing something like making this task run 5 times faster?

Comment: If you want each thread to do one fifth of the task, it's up to you to divide the task into five independent pieces. Note that doing things simultaneously is no guarantee that they run faster; that depends on how your JVM and your operating system cooperate in assigning processor cores to tasks and whether your system has additional cores available for the task. Multitasking isn't magic. Unless you already know your problem is particularly well suited to it because there are delays when you're waiting for data from network or disk, it may not improve speed at all.

Comment: Before doing performance work on a Java program, I *highly* recommend obtaining a good performance analyzer and running the code under that. The bottlenecks may not be where you expect them to be, and it's easy to waste a lot of effort trying to improve something that doesn't matter while missing the easy improvement elsewhere.

Comment: Daniel, you got it right. I want to make 5 threads run the same task; each one updates a unique row in DB, though.

Comment: Keshlam, I am pretty sure that my job is going to get faster with multithreading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to misconceive what is actually happening. Creating the executor service with an argument of `5` doesn't make it execute the `Runnable` you submit 5 times; it merely creates five available threads, but you only submit one piece of work, which itself carries out your loop. The only result is that you carry out the work in a different thread, not in parallel. Four of your threads will lie idle while the fifth runs the single `Runnable` you submit.

What you want to do instead is to remove the loop from your runnable and then submit the work five times instead. For instance, like this:

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    service.execute(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            doWork();
        }
    });
}
service.shutdown();
```

Comment: Thanks Dolda2000. I understand your point and even I agree with you, after having read about multithreading in short.